# PThread robust mutex not working

Tags: c++, pthreads, shared-memory, interprocess

For interprocess programs, when a process acquires a mutex lock and the process is killed by a user, the lock never gets unlocked and another process which is waiting to acquire the same lock, just keeps waiting.

I did an extensive search and found that `pthreads` has the concept of a `robust lock` to solve the problem, but on trying it, the ordinary locking between processes itself is not working.
For the below code, I opened two terminals and ran the executable in both terminals.
In both, the program acquired the lock immediately. Expected behaviour was that the first executable I ran would acquire the lock and the second executable would wait for 30 seconds. But that doesn't happen. Have I implemented it wrong? (Compile with `-lpthread`)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include<iostream>

pthread_mutex_t shm_mutex;

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
    std::cout<<"Beginning\n";


    err = pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_init(&shm_mutex, &mattr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);


    std::cout<<"Before locking\n";
    //err = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr); if (err) return err;
    err = pthread_mutex_lock(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;
    std::cout<<"locked\n";

    sleep(30);

    err = pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;
    std::cout<<"Unlocked\n";
    err = pthread_mutex_destroy(&shm_mutex); if (err) return err;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two related problems:

1. The second process called `pthread_mutex_init` on the mutex, which destroys it, since it was already created *and* *locked* by the first process.
2. You didn't actually *share* the mutex by putting it in shared memory. You had each process create its own mutex in its own address space.

Comment: So how is the mutex put into a common shared memory? I've tried a lot already. Even in this program (http://www.redhat.com/archives/phil-list/2003-June/msg00000.html), the forked process would be going through `pthread_rwlock_init`.

Comment: @Nav They can map the same file. You can create a shared mapping before you `fork`. You can use SysV shared memory using `shm_open`. But you need to create a mutex in shared memory somehow.